# Does Canada issue Study Permits for Part-time graduate programs?

Tags: canada, student-visa

Does Canada issue Study Permits for Part-time graduate programs?

For international students from the Indian subcontinent (India, Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Bangladesh, Nepal, Bhutan, and so on)?

To study Masters and PhD?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, and a student's country of origin is not the consideration but, rather, the program into which one is accepted.

According to the [Government of Canada information on](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/students/consider.asp)

> **Full-time versus part-time studies**
>
> The definition of full-time or part-time varies depending on the educational institution. A study permit may be issued whether or not the student’s studies are on a full-time or part-time basis (i.e., the condition that study permit holders must actively pursue studies does not require them to be enrolled on a full-time basis), as long as they are enrolled at a [designated learning institution](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/students/design.asp). However, the student must have a full-time status in order to work on or off campus.